# Propensity score matching with multiple imputation

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice, propensity-score-matching

I have a dataset with a couple of missing values and would need to run a propensity score matching using the variable 'y' as Treatment variable and x1, x2 and x3 as variables for adjustment.
By using the following code with Matchit

```
ModMatch <- matchit(y ~ x1+x2+x3, method = 'nearest', data = data)
```

I obtain the error 'Missing values exist in the data'

I have therefore tried to run a multiple imputation using mice:

```
ImputedDF <- mice(data)
ModMatch <- matchit(y ~ x1+x2+x3, method = 'nearest', data = ImputedDF)
```

And I get the error 'cannot coerce an object of class mids to a dataframe'.
I would probably need a way to print an imputed data frame, could anyone know if that is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `MatchThem` package, was was specifically designed for performing matching after multiple imputation. The `matchthem()` function calls `matchit()` and performs matching within each imputed dataset. You can then check balance in the imputed dataset using the `cobalt` package, which was designed to be compatible with `MatchThem`. Afterward, you can use the `with()` function in `MatchThem` to estimate the effect. Here's an example of this workflow:

```
library(mice); library(MatchThem); library(cobalt)

#Impute the data with 20 imputations (more is better)
imp <- mice(data, m = 20)

#Perform matching within each imputation
ModMatch <- matchthem(y ~ x1+x2+x3, method = 'nearest', data = imp)

#Assess balance
bal.tab(ModMatch, un = TRUE)
love.plot(Modmatch)

#Estimate the effect
summary(pool(with(ModMatch, svyglm(outcome ~ y + x1 + X2 + X2))))
```

I would caution you that you are using advanced statistical techniques that should not be used by someone without advanced training. Using the defaults in `mice` and `MatchThem` is rarely a good idea.

Regarding the error messages you were getting: the output of a call to `mice()` is not a data frame; it's a `mids` object. The `data` argument in `matchit()` requires a data frame. `matchthem()` accepts a `mids` object to perform the matching within each imputed dataset.

Comment: Can you recommend any literature about what settings to use in mice (instead of the defaults)?

Comment: @E_H https://doi.org/10.1093/aje/kwt312 on which imputation method to use; in general, you should opt for way more imputations and way more iterations than are the default. See [here](https://statisticalhorizons.com/how-many-imputations/) for information about the number of imputations. You might want to ask a separate question on CV about this.